# What type of outlet has a button and small hole in the middle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, home-automation

I just had a home inspection done for a home we are planning to purchase. The home inspector saw an electrical outlet and didn't know what the part in the middle was for/what was special about it.

> The outlet at the front right corner of the family room is one I have
>   not seen before, as shown in the following photo. I believe this
>   outlet is designed for use with electrical equipment such as stereos
>   and TVs. This is not a GFCI (Ground FaultCircuit Interrupting) outlet.

My first thought was home automation of some kind, but as I'm not in the house yet, not sure. Does anyone recognize it from the photo?

[image: Electrical Outlet]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks a lot like a GoControl W015Z-1 Z-wave smart receptacle.  [See here](http://www.gocontrol.com/detail.php?productId=23)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a safety device for closing the ports when not in use, so children won't push anything into it.

Comment: Did you not find the existing answer, with its resource link, convincing?